# Android:getting place name from network provider

Tags: android, gps

I am building a GPS application which DO NOT USE INTERNET.so i cannot use APIs to obtain location.

I have already extracted latitude and longitude from network provider.
i was wondering if i can extract current place name from the network provider.By default a place name is displayed along with the network provider name(cell info display).I would like to extract it programmatically..can i do it

Answer (score 0):

> i was wondering if i can extract current place name from the network provider

No, sorry.